# Unexpected token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, babel-loader

I got an error as below when I try to use `material-ui-dropzone` in ReactJs.

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/material-ui-dropzone/src/index.js
Module parse failed: /home/buddhik/Documents/InternWork/React/licensemanager/node_modules/material-ui-dropzone/src/index.js Unexpected token (106:31)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     }
|
|     handleRequestCloseSnackBar = () => {
|         this.setState({
|             openSnackBar: false,
 @ ./src/scenes/license/RequestLicense.jsx 13:26-57
 @ ./src/app.jsx
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./index.js
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    entry: {
        index: './index.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                }],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        query: {
                            presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|cur|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: ['url-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader',
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                }, {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                }],
            },

        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', '.scss'],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '/dist',
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/dist/bundle.js',
          }
    },

};
```

And here is my `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "reference-react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Reference React App",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --progress --history-api-fallback",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .jsx --ext .js",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.19.4",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "^1.0.3",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-cookies": "^0.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-pagination-table": "^1.1.0",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-router-server-location": "^2.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "universal-cookie": "^2.1.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "eslint": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

Can someone help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are excluding `node_modules` in the following

```
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
```

Remove the `exclude: /node_modules/'` and i see no reason why that shouldn't fix the issue.

Though that can fix the issue, you might want to do the same with the loader `test: /\.jsx?$/`.